# Cannot access API in my android app which was created by AWS EC2 as backend

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Cannot access API in my android app which was created by `AWS EC2` as backend.

URL I have used is "http://ec2-52-88-152-29.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/values"

Here is my code.

```
public class ServiceHelper {
JSONObject JSONresponseText;
Context context;
JSONObject jsonResultText;

public ServiceHelper(Context context) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    this.context = context;

}

public JSONObject jsonSendHTTPRequest(String requestData,
                                      String requestURL, String requestType) {
    try {
        if (!Constants.isConnectingToInternet(context)) {
            JSONresponseText = new JSONObject();
            JSONresponseText.put(Constants.KEY_ERROR,
                    Constants.TOAST_INTERNET);
        } else {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                Log.e("request data", requestData + Constants.EMPTY_STRING
                        + requestURL);
                URL object = new URL(requestURL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod(requestType);
                connection.setRequestProperty(Constants.KEY_CONTENT_TYPE,
                        Constants.VALUE_CONTENT_TYPE);
                connection.setRequestProperty(Constants.KEY_ACCEPT,
                        Constants.VALUE_CONTENT_TYPE);

               if (requestType
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.POST_METHOD)) {
                OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());                    
                streamWriter.write(requestData);
                streamWriter.flush();
                }

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                            connection.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            streamReader);
                    String response = null;
                    while ((response = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(response + "\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    Log.d("Result Value ", stringBuilder.toString());
                    jsonResultText = new JSONObject(
                            stringBuilder.toString());
                    return jsonResultText;
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHelper", connection.getResponseMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                Log.e("ServiceHelper", exception.toString());
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ServiceHelper", e.toString());
    }
    return JSONresponseText;
 }
}
```

Log Values are

```
    08-28 22:18:39.282 21499-21499/com.demo.demoaws D/Response Code: 204
    08-28 22:18:39.282 21499-21499/com.demo.demoaws E/ServiceHelper: No Content
```

I got the response as `No Content`. I don't know what is the problem. Does I have to attach Header as any of `AWS credentials`. Can anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is request type in your case?

Comment: Can you share your log

Comment: GET is the request Type @Jack'sretardedcode

Comment: I have shared my log details ..check it out @cafebabe1991

Comment: Check your JSON implementation on both ends.

Comment: But it works if i use volley library..So most probably  backend not be problem..@Jack'sretardedcode

Comment: Finally it works by removing setOutput(true) in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Use library **OkHttpClient** for network calls.

Library makes life easier.

add dependencies in your **build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.survivingwithandroid:weatherlib_okhttpclient:1.6.0'
```

Now do network call with OkHttpClient library

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://ec2-52-88-152-29.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/values")
  .get()
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
String jsonData = response.body().string();
```

There is chrome extension [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) which will also generate OkHttpClient code for your api calls.

Comment: Already i tried use of  volley library it works..But I want to know why its not in HttpUrlConnection. Anyway thanks  @Yogesh